Read values from default model in SAPUI5
I am trying to read Model values from Global model:
this.getView().getModel().oData['Requests(WorkItemGroup=\'000000092008\',Approver=\'800365\',RequestNumber=\'829\')']

I tried to use:
this.getView().getModel().oData[this.g_eventContextPath]

But its not working.
this.g_eventContextPath = "Requests(WorkItemGroup=\'000000092008\',Approver=\'800365\',RequestNumber=\'829\')"


Usually you retrieve data from an Odata service with requestObject().
This is described in the documentation Accessing Data in Controller Code
